# Normal-to-uniform transform preserving standard deviation

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

When transforming a normal distribution to a uniform distribution preserving both the mean and the standard deviation, the bounds of the uniform distribution must be the original mean plus or minus a constant scaling factor:

$$ a = \mu - \sqrt 3 \sigma $$
$$ b = \mu + \sqrt 3 \sigma $$

How is the $ \sqrt 3 $ found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density function $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}\sigma}$ for $a\le x\le b$. Thus the variance $=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}\sigma}\int_a^b (x-\mu)^2dx=\sigma^2$.

Comment: I assume this corresponds to the definition for _Absolutely continuous random variable_ in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: f(x) is constant - therefore abs. continuous.